# PHP Zend_Db_Statement_DB2 returns null for static field

Tags: php, sql, db2, zend-db

I am building my SQL statement through a PHP API, and then passing it through a module that connects to our database (DB2).

My issue: a **static field** (sales_type) is returning null when passing the SQL through a Zend_Db_Statement_DB2 module.  Running the SQL directly on our AS400 (command line), it works properly.  When I pass the same SQL through the DB2 module the "sales_type" field is null for all rows.

A simplified version of the query:

```
SELECT 'discount' "sales_type", sum(sales_type1) "sales" FROM salesTable
UNION
SELECT 'promotion' "sales_type", sum(sales_type2) "sales" FROM salesTable
```

Expected/Desired results with fictiscious sales (what is also returned on command line):

```
sales_type     sales
discount       12345
promotion       6789
```

Returned results when SQL passed through DB2 module:

```
sales_type     sales
null           12345
null            6789
```

The PHP code used to execute *select queries* is listed below:

```
    public static function ExecuteSelect($sql)
{
    $adapter = new Zend_Db_Adapter_Db2(Zend_Registry::get('config')->resources->multidb->as400)

    //Prepare the SQL Statement
    $sqlStmt = new Zend_Db_Statement_DB2($adapter, $sql);

    $sqlStmt->execute();
    $rows = $sqlStmt->fetchAll();

    return $rows;
}
```

Can anyone give me more insight as to the cause of this issue and how to fix it?  Also, I'm not looking for a post-processing php work-around. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see this link **posted below** for a solution. The CCSID needs to be set to 37 for both the user and the job running the query

[PHP / SQL - Convert EBCDIC to ASCII](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16339650/php-sql-convert-ebcdic-to-ascii)