# PHP / SQL - Convert EBCDIC to ASCII

Tags: php, sql, ascii, ibm-midrange, ebcdic

We have PHP server code, executing SQL statements against our iSeries midrange.

Here is a simplified version of the SQL query

```
SELECT 'Regular' "sales_type", sum(sales_type1) "sales" FROM salesTable
```

The query executes just fine, the problem is that **when using a static field/value such as 'SomeText' "Title"** and the results come back in PHP, they are not in the desired format

```
string(7) "م�����"
```

To connect to the system and retrieve the results

```
db2_connect ( '*LOCAL', 'user', 'pass' );
if (! $connection) {[error code]}
$stmt = db2_prepare ( $connection, $strSql );
if (! db2_execute ( $stmt ) ) { [error code ]
while ( $row = db2_fetch_array ( $stmt ) ) {
   var_dump($row[1]);
}
```

We are on PHP version 5.2.17

Our iSeries is V7R1M0

A solution to convert server side with PHP or in the SQL query its self would be great.

Thanks!

---

**Edit**

From bucks suggestion we have changed the user profile CCSID to 37 instead of 65535

Now we get back (below) which is a bit closer...

```
string(7) "Ù…‡¤“™"
```

Is this possibly because we only changed the user?  Does the system, job or table need to be changed too?

---

**Edit 2**

Here is the phpinfo output

```
_COOKIE["ZDEDebuggerPresent"]   php,phtml,php3
_SERVER["ZendEnablerConfig"]    /www/zendserver/conf/fastcgi.conf
_SERVER["PHPRC"]    /usr/local/ZendSvr/etc/
_SERVER["PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN"]    40
_SERVER["PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS"]    0
_SERVER["CCSID"]    819
_SERVER["LANG"] C
_SERVER["INSTALLATION_UID"] 20101203131436121338
_SERVER["LDR_CNTRL"]    MAXDATA=0x40000000
_SERVER["LIBPATH"]  /usr/local/ZendSvr/lib
_SERVER["DB2NOEXITLIST"]    TRUE
_SERVER["ORACLE_HOME"]  .
_SERVER["ORA_NLS10"]    no value
_SERVER["ORA_NLS_PROFILE33"]    no value
_SERVER["FCGI_ROLE"]    RESPONDER
_SERVER["REDIRECT_UNIQUE_ID"]   UYKvWcCoAQIAAnZHWG8AABS@
_SERVER["REDIRECT_STATUS"]  200
_SERVER["UNIQUE_ID"]    UYKvWcCoAQIAAnZHWG8AABS@
_SERVER["QIBM_USE_DESCRIPTOR_STDIO"]    Y
_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]    vmas400.vm.com:10090
_SERVER["HTTP_CONNECTION"]  keep-alive
_SERVER["HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH"]    XMLHttpRequest
_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.64 Safari/537.31
_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"] application/x-www-form-urlencoded
_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT"]  */*
_SERVER["REFERER"]  http://vmas400.vm.com:10090ZendServer/Index/Index
_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"] http://vmas400.vm.com:10090/ZendServer/Index/Index
_SERVER["REFERER_URL"]  http://vmas400.vm.com:10090/ZendServer/Index/Index
_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING"] gzip,deflate,sdch
_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"] en-US,en;q=0.8
_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET"]  ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
_SERVER["HTTP_COOKIE"]  ZENDSERVERSESSID=7asfv608qffhv556msem6evi66; CosmeticContest=16062; CompanyWithStoreDetail=16061; TYLYClassAnalysis=16068; OrderDetail=17220; RmsOrders=17221; DailyReceipts=16063; DailySales=17562; OnOrder=16064; OpenPurchaseOrders=17566; RegularPriceRankings=17568; ReviewStatistics=17570; SalesAndStock=17573; StocksByPeriod=17575; Top10BestSellers=17577; ReplenishmentAssortment=17269; RABS=17616; FreeFormatSku=16473; TYLYSalesAndOH=21294; SalesRecapByDate=16312; VendorAgendaSummary=23219; BasicStock=23474; InStock=16067; RegSalesAvgStockSummary=21270; TYLYSalesMDGMByStore=23822; VendorAgenda=23826; Header=16066; usc=adam; hudi[u]=d106b7a04c0d94b8a0e7624a017ead98324b57e8; hudi[i]=fec51923e58c84db4647d2b3e11fe03ec3f0c202; FreeFormat=16506; __utma=118969486.352613215.1355776933.1365626094.1367348033.12; __utmz=118969486.1355776933.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); ZDEDebuggerPresent=php,phtml,php3
_SERVER["PATH"] /bin:/usr/bin:/usr/ucb:/usr/bsd:/usr/local/bin
_SERVER["SERVER_SIGNATURE"] no value
_SERVER["SERVER_SOFTWARE"]  Apache
_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]  vmas400.vm.com
_SERVER["SERVER_ADDR"]  192.168.1.2
_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"]  80
_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]  172.16.129.193
_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]    /www/zendserver/htdocs/prod
_SERVER["SERVER_ADMIN"] [no address given]
_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]  /usr/local/zendsvr/gui/html/index.php
_SERVER["DOCUMENT_NAME"]    /usr/local/zendsvr/gui/html/index.php
_SERVER["REMOTE_PORT"]  14259
_SERVER["REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING"]    dojo.preventCache=1367519066445
_SERVER["REDIRECT_URL"] /ZendServer/Information/Phpinfo
_SERVER["GATEWAY_INTERFACE"]    CGI/1.1
_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]  HTTP/1.1
_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]   GET
_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"] dojo.preventCache=1367519066445
_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]  /ZendServer/Information/Phpinfo?dojo.preventCache=1367519066445
_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]  /ZendServer/index.php
_SERVER["DOCUMENT_URI"] /ZendServer/index.php
_SERVER["RULE_FILE"]    conf/httpd.conf
_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] /ZendServer/index.php
_SERVER["REQUEST_TIME"] 1367519066
```

---

**EDIT**

**SOLUTION**

The solution was to change the user profile to use CCSID 37, and the server jobs to use CCSID 37.  We will make a manual change so that when the jobs are restarted, they do not revert.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The conversion can happen automatically if the IBM side is configured properly.  Have the IBM admin check the system value QCCSID.  If it's set to 65535, that's why no translation is taking place.  65535 says that all the data on the system is binary and should never be translated.  There is a hierarchy of CCSIDs.  It starts at the system level with QCCSID, moves down to the user profile and finally down to the individual table.  This is to handle systems where multiple languages are in use.

The main reason systems are at 65535 is because when the distant ancestor of the current midrange machines was deployed, there was a single language; one EBCDIC, and when multiple languages were introduced, the default language was set to 'do not translate'.

EBCDIC is no longer a single character set.  There is one encoding for each language.  US English is CCSID(37).  If it turns out that CCSID is the issue, have the admin create a test user profile with the proper CCSID and try that.

**EDIT 1:** I just did a test on my machine.

**EDIT 2:** Added a literal to the returned columns.

```
<?php
  //Establish connection to database
  $host = "midrange";
  $conn = db2_connect ($host, user, pass);
?>

<table width="75%" border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" bgcolor="#eeeeee">
<tr>
  <td><b>Name</b></td>
  <td><b>Email</b></td>
  <td><b>3rd column</b></td>
</tr>

<?php
$query = 'Select name, email, \'Markdown\' "THIRD" from table';

//Execute query
$queryexe = db2_exec($conn, $query) ;

//Fetch results
while(db2_fetch_row($queryexe)) {
 $name  = db2_result($queryexe, 'NAME');
 $email = db2_result($queryexe, 'EMAIL');
 $const = db2_result($queryexe, 'THIRD');

//Put the results in an HTML table.
print("<tr bgcolor=#ffffff>\n");
print("<td>$name</td>\n");
print("<td>$email</td>\n");
print("<td>$const</td>\n");
print("</tr>\n");
}
?>
</table>
```

All my tables are CCSID(37)  IBM i 7.1.
phpinfo() reports IBM_DB2 1.9.0, PHP 5.3.3  I note that I have iconv support enabled and my server CCSID is 819 - US ASCII.

**Edit 3:** very partial phpinfo()

```
ibm_db2
IBM DB2, Cloudscape and Apache Derby support    enabled
Module release  1.9.0
Module revision     $Revision: 297218 $
Binary data mode (ibm_db2.binmode)  DB2_BINARY
DB2 instance name (ibm_db2.instance_name)   no value

iconv
iconv support   enabled
iconv implementation    IBM iconv
iconv library version   unknown

Directive   Local Value Master Value
iconv.input_encoding    ISO8859-1   ISO8859-1
iconv.internal_encoding ISO8859-1   ISO8859-1
iconv.output_encoding   ISO8859-1   ISO8859-1
Environment
Variable    Value
ZendEnablerConfig   /www/zendsvr/conf/fastcgi.conf
PHPRC   /usr/local/ZendSvr/etc/
PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN   5
PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS   0
CCSID   819
LANG    en_US
INSTALLATION_UID    20101215125734236656
LIBPATH     /usr/local/ZendSvr/lib
DB2NOEXITLIST   TRUE

PHP Variables
Variable    Value
_REQUEST["TJE"] no value
_REQUEST["TE3"] no value
_REQUEST["ZDEDebuggerPresent"]  php,phtml,php3
_COOKIE["TJE"]  no value
_COOKIE["TE3"]  no value
_COOKIE["ZDEDebuggerPresent"]   php,phtml,php3
_SERVER["ZendEnablerConfig"]    /www/zendsvr/conf/fastcgi.conf
_SERVER["PHPRC"]    /usr/local/ZendSvr/etc/
_SERVER["PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN"]    5
_SERVER["PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS"]    0
_SERVER["CCSID"]    819
_SERVER["LANG"] en_US
_SERVER["INSTALLATION_UID"] 20101215125734236656
_SERVER["LIBPATH"]  /usr/local/ZendSvr/lib
_SERVER["DB2NOEXITLIST"]    TRUE
_SERVER["FCGI_ROLE"]    RESPONDER
_SERVER["SCRIPT_URL"]   /hello.php
_SERVER["QIBM_USE_DESCRIPTOR_STDIO"]    Y
_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0
_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT"]  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"] en-US,en;q=0.5
_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING"] gzip, deflate
_SERVER["HTTP_DNT"] 1
_SERVER["HTTP_CONNECTION"]  keep-alive
_SERVER["HTTP_PRAGMA"]  no-cache
_SERVER["HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL"]   no-cache
_SERVER["PATH"] /bin:/usr/bin:/usr/ucb:/usr/bsd:/usr/local/bin
_SERVER["SERVER_SIGNATURE"] no value
_SERVER["SERVER_SOFTWARE"]  Apache
_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]    /www/zendsvr/htdocs
_SERVER["SERVER_ADMIN"] [no address given]
_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]  /www/zendsvr/htdocs/hello.php
_SERVER["DOCUMENT_NAME"]    /www/zendsvr/htdocs/hello.php
_SERVER["REMOTE_PORT"]  54747
_SERVER["GATEWAY_INTERFACE"]    CGI/1.1
_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]  HTTP/1.1
_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]   GET
_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"] no value
_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]  /hello.php
_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]  /hello.php
_SERVER["DOCUMENT_URI"] /hello.php
_SERVER["RULE_FILE"]    conf/httpd.conf
_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] /hello.php
_SERVER["REQUEST_TIME"] 1367514482
```

**Edit 4:** How to make server jobs CCSID(37)

There are several ways to get the server jobs to run US English.  It's an admin decision as to which is lowest impact on the overall server operation.  I set my US English-only system to go to QCCSID 37 over a IPL and have seen no issues.

1. `CHGSYSVAL QCCSID 37` - This will set the entire server to US English.  Restart the Apache server to take effect.
2. `CHGUSRPRF QTMHHTTP CCSID(37)` - This will set all of the HTTP server jobs to US English.  Restart the Apache server to take effect.
3. Reconfigure the Apache server. Set `CgiConvMode EBCDIC` and `DefaultNetCCSID 819` and `CGIJobCCSID 37`  Restart the Apache server to take effect.  See [CGI Data Conversions](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/rzaie/rzag3ch1envvar.htm) for the details.  This will set one Apache server's jobs to US English.
4. `CHGPF ... CCSID(37)` - This will set the file to US English.  Need to alter them all.

This isn't intended to be all inclusive.  More like a rundown of how the hierarchy fits together.

Comment: Well... one step closer i think.  (see edits to OP)  We changed the user profile to 37 instead of *SYSVAL and now we get back string(7) "Ù…‡¤“™" string(8) "Ô™’„–¦•"     which is a little closer to actual characters...  any ideas?  - - thank you in advance!

Comment: What values are you expecting to see?  The SELECT statement only has 2 columns, but the variables are 'string(7)' and 'string(8)'. Can you show the hexadecimal value of what is being returned?

Comment: I would expect to see "Regular" and "Markdown" from the OP. *or at the least, common English letters :)*...   I did have different titles in the example than my live code, sorry.  I've made the edits to show the correct title being used.  The response is short by one character which is odd.  The two hex values being returned are "d98587a4938199" and "d48199928496a695" just being repeated.  Removed the repeats to avoid confusion.

Comment: I added a working example on my 7.1 machine.  Maybe looking at phpinfo() will help.  Your hex strings are in fact US EBCDIC CCSID 37.

Comment: Normal queries such as that work fine.  It's when you specify static values in the SQL query instead of pulling from a column.

Comment: I'm getting a message that 819 is not a valid CCSID for the user profile.  Will continue to experiment.

Comment: Translations need two encodings.  The DB2 side is US EBCDIC (37) and the web side is US ASCII (819).  See additional edit showing phpinfo() output.

Comment: I've verified the phpinfo section, and it was set to 819 already =[  made an edit to my OP to show

Comment: OK, to verify, two columns are being returned, the literal and a sales amount.  The literal is coming back as EBCDIC and the sales amount is readable ASCII?  Or is the problem that all columns are coming back EBCDIC but only when there is a literal in the SELECT?  Check the web server job (WRKSBSJOB QHTTPSVR) to see that it is using CCSID 37.  Then check the .php file (WRKLNK) on the server to make sure it's either 819 or 1252.

Comment: GENIUS!  I went through and changed the jobs to be CCSID 37 and ran it, then it worked!  When the server restarts it will go back though.  Can you edit your answer with your fix and possibly how to make this change perminent (if possible?)  Thank you so much for your help! 1000 upvotes!

Answer (score 1):

I have discovered a better way to do this... Using the [TRANSLATE or ForceTranslation keyword](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_61/rzaik/rzaikconnstrkeywordstranprop.htm) in your DSN. For example:

```
odbc:DRIVER={iSeries Access ODBC Driver};SYSTEM=as400.myserver.local;TRANSLATE=1;
```

You don't have to change any files, system settings or use CAST in your queries.